# How to tell if something is a vector or points at a vector in R

Tags: r

If I have a function with argument `x`, and assuming that function expects `x` to be a vector, how do I test whether `x` is a vector or is something that points at a vector?

```
fun <- function(x) {
  brilliant manipulation of x here
  output based on manipulation of x here
  }
```

For example, how would I differentiate case 1:

```
myvector <- c(1,2,3)
fun(myvector)
```

from case 2:

```
fun(c(1,2,3))
```

I would like `fun()` to be able to output `"Output concerning myvector"` for case 1.

I would like `fun()` to be able to output `"Output concerning x"` for case 2.

I am lost amidst `substitute`, `deparse`, and various and sundry related ideas. Illumination appreciated.

Comment: The distinction between "a vector" and "points at a vector" isn't exactly clear here. For example, what do you want `fun(myvector + myvector)` to display?

Comment: @DavidRobinson Good question. Hadn't thought of that... I suppose I will have to and ask new questions as they arise. :)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Although (with your example) defaulting to `x` per Mr. Flick's answer works for my purposes. Would I have to get deep into parsing to identify such beasts? Or are there readily available tools in R(/S) to recognize *expressions*?

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote, and am happy to take constructive criticism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
fun<-function(x) {
    pp<-substitute(x)
    nn<- if(is.name(pp)) {
        deparse(pp)
    } else {
        "x"
    }
    paste("Output concerning", nn)
}

myvector <- c(1,2,3)
fun(c(1,2,3))
# [1] "Output concerning x"
fun(myvector)
# [1] "Output concerning myvector"
```

We use `substitute` to look at what was passed. If it was a `name`, assume it was a variable name and `deparse()` it to get the character version of the name, otherwise use "x".

Answer (score 1):

```
fun <- function(x) { if(is.name( substitute(x) ) ){ print(TRUE)}; return(x) }
```

Mr Flick's answer appears somewhat more informative, but I thought adding a minimal example might also be helpful.

Comment: Hmmm... `fun <- function(x) {return(is.name(substitute(x)))}`?

Comment: I sense a demurral but I am unable to discern the issue. Hit me with a bigger cluestick.

Comment: Oh, no. I appreciate (and upvoted) your answer. My comment was just an attempt to condense your one-liner (albeit into a function returning TRUE/FALSE).

Comment: Ah. I was thinking to emulate the `print.*` methods which generally return their arguments. Be sure to upvote MrFlick's answer since mine wasn't fully responsive.